# How to activate only single controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

In my app I configured controllers as services, i.e. in `Startup.ConfigureServices` I have:

```
  services.AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices() 
    ...
```

and in `Program.Main` I have:

```
            IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
                {
                    options.ValidateOnBuild = false; 
                    ...
```

and it worked until I added mirror-controller. So now I have two controllers (one "real", one "dummy") with the exactly same endpoints and I register only one of them. So in theory when hitting given endpoint I should have only single match.

But it is not the case, ASP.Net somehow digs up everything and discovers I have two controllers (despite the second one is not registered), as the effect I get error "The request matched multiple endpoints".

So, how to have two mirror controllers within the project and enable only one of them? Or maybe in other words -- having some controllers within the project how to enable and disable them programmatically (in runtime)?

*I could change the approach and provide single controller, and inside have double logic -- one directing to real action, another directing to dummy action. Or some other approach with single controller. But I would like to better understand what is going on.*

Comment: I don't understand why you would want this in the first place? What is the benefit of having this "mirror" controller?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing far too much in your controllers. Action methods should be only a few lines of code, inject functionality into them via DI.

Comment: @DavidG, you are 200% correct, yet, this is not the topic of this question. I register controllers manually, and yet ASP.Net digs them out automatically. I would like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: What do you mean that you register them manually? What do you think `AddControllers` is doing?

Comment: @DavidG this is what I would like to find out. I have read that `AddControllersAsServices` changes the default behaviour and after that you register controllers yourself.

Comment: Then you read wrong. `AddControllersAsServices` just uses DI to instantiate controllers rather than the `DefaultControllerActivator` (I think)

Comment: @DavidG, thank you. In such case how this Startup call should look like?

Comment: In what case? Not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: @DavidG, Startup? In case you would like to manually register controllers and not use of all available controllers within the project.

Comment: You could possibly write your own controller activator, but that is a really hacky way to achieve what you are trying to do here so not something I'm going to advise on.